# Wordpress Sendgrid Email wasn't sent

Tags: wordpress, sendgrid

I was trying to setup WordPress to send email using Sendgrid. I have created free sendgrid account, senders identity and API key following [this](https://wpengine.com/support/configuring-sendgrid-for-wordpress/) document

But when I try to send test email under **SendGrid Test - Send a test email with these settings**

I see **Email wasn't sent.** at the top

What I am missing here ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error, however because their official plugin is only checking `wp_mail` is `true` ([source](https://github.com/sendgrid/wordpress/blob/60b0a730675755e40a8a08744eb2ea5bf3725cb3/lib/class-sendgrid-settings.php#L808-L820)). I decided it wasn't worth digging into their plugin as its unmaintained, so I setup an SMTP relay API key and used [Easy WP SMTP plugin](https://en-nz.wordpress.org/plugins/easy-wp-smtp/) instead.

1. Create SMTP relay API on send grid [docs](https://sendgrid.com/docs/for-developers/sending-email/integrating-with-the-smtp-api/).
2. Configure Easy WP SMTP settings (it's platform agnostic, so you'll need to make sure you have the correct settings. Mine were: `server: smtp.sendgrid.net // SMTP port: 465 // SMTP Auth: yes // Username: apikey // Password: Generated API key.`

This is a workaround due to 3 things really: Time, unmaintained plugin and lack of verbose/useful error reporting from said plugin. *Mileage may vary with this "solution".*

**Edit:** Duh, the actual way I got this error was because I had the SMTP server address copy pasta incorrect. Ensure the smtp server is copy pasta'd correctly.